# How to run CodedUI tests outside application with Batch files and create a report

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests, acceptance

I managed to create [Page Object Model](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) UIMap test cases for acceptance testing in Visual Studio 2013. I'm having issues on how to run test them outside application with Batch files and create a report.

Comment: Most of what you wrote is not relevant to your question. Even worse, once I removed the part that was not relevant, there was no question remaining. What is your exact problem?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I'm working on proof of concept to show stakeholders why we need CodedUI. All my test cases are inside application. is there is a way to call the test case outside the app?

Comment: What do you mean, "inside the app"? Inside _which_ app?

Comment: I created call's for controllers for simple use cases in front end to test API's flow of the website with assertions.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "inside the app".

Comment: My apologies for confusion, I created a Codeui project with few test cases and assertions. is it possible to run test case from outside the project without using MTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mstest tool for drive test from command line more detail see:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/running_coded_ui_on_vm/archive/2013/03/25/running-coded-ui-on-vm-using-mstest.aspx

simple MSTEST.EXE /testcontainer:"LOCATION OF YOUR BINARY (DLL)

if you configured TFS server, you could also publish the test result to TFS server, then get a test report.

Comment: Blog is very helpful thanks! I have few question. In Blog says: 2) Copy and Paste the binary ( DLL) from your system to VMs on which you want to run coded UI.  I'm lost where to add DLL file. Do we need to add DLL in project in reference?

Comment: The DLL is the test project dll, which will be generated when you compile the project,  It is under some folder like bin/debug or bin/release folder.  I think you'd better not copy single dll out, it work when you run "mstest.exe PATHToDLL\**.dll"    //The copy action in blog is to run the test on other VM, since you don't need to run on other machine, you can skip the step.

Comment: I think vstest.console.exe is prefered since VS2012: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx

Comment: Yes, vstest is new in VS2012 and also cover the funcion of mstest.